# Trying to filter Wordpress query by custom taxonomy terms

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to filter a Wordpress query based on terms in a custom taxonomy.  I'm using the Essential Grid plugin to show posts from a custom post type 'offer'.

I'd like to grab values from the 'f' URL parameter and then use those values as the terms for filtering the query.

I'm not sure why my code isn't working.  When I try to save it, I get a message that it will cause a fatal error.

Can someone with more PHP experience help me out?  I've gone through the code multiple times and haven't seen the issue.  Tested several variations as well.

```
function eg_mod_query($query, $grid_id){

if($grid_id == 3) {
 $f = $_GET['f'];
    $filters = explode(', ', $f);
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'offer',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'offer_taxonomy',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array($filters),
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$filters = explode(', ', $f);
```

Line above is already in an array format. You should not change that to

```
array($filters).
```

In args var which changes the format.

**I think this should work:**

```
function eg_mod_query($query, $grid_id){

if($grid_id == 3) {

    $f = $_GET['f'];
    $filters = explode(', ', $f);
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'offer',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'offer_taxonomy',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $filters,
            ),
        ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
}

return $query;
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I removed the array format where you suggested.  There was still a fatal error, so I deleted some other code I had commented out.  That worked to stop the fatal error.  However, instead of showing posts from my custom post type 'offer', it's just showing my regular blog posts.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you making sure post_type is referred Properly? Like for example pages, post type can be found here: https://prnt.sc/qf1mru ?

Comment: Yes it is the correct name.  I just double checked and the cpt is 'offer'